# Can I watch for single file change with WatchService (not the whole directory)?

Tags: java, watchservice

When I'm trying to register a file instead of a directory `java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException` is thrown. Can I listen for a single file change, not the whole directory?

Comment: Javadoc: "In this release, this path locates a directory that exists." ==> so the answer is "no, you cannot register a file". Then: "The directory is registered with the watch service so that entries in the directory can be watched." ==> so registering a directory actually watches for events on directory entries, not on the directory itself. The name of the events remind of what they are related to, they start with ENTRY_, like "ENTRY_MODIFY - entry in directory was modified". The selected answer provides the details for using the event.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Just filter the events for the file you want in the directory:

```
final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
System.out.println(path);
try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
    final WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
    while (true) {
        final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
            //we only register "ENTRY_MODIFY" so the context is always a Path.
            final Path changed = (Path) event.context();
            System.out.println(changed);
            if (changed.endsWith("myFile.txt")) {
                System.out.println("My file has changed");
            }
        }
        // reset the key
        boolean valid = wk.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            System.out.println("Key has been unregisterede");
        }
    }
}
```

Here we check whether the changed file is "myFile.txt", if it is then do whatever.

Comment: I met text editor (krViewer) which don't modify file, but create tmp file and on Save just replace file, so no MODIFY message issued and i had to chech CREATE also.

Comment: Is there any chance hat WatchService listen for files which exists currently in directory? So I start the project and files are there exactly. 

So far, only way to INITIALIZE WatchService was changing name of existing files, oraz just creating one.

Comment: Don't forget to test if the event is `OVERFLOW`. You don't need to register for this. Example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#process).

Comment: The unspoken trap here is that some platforms' implementations of the watcher can lock the directory you put the watcher on.

Comment: final WatchKey watchKey - what's this for? This variable doesn't seem to be used later.

Comment: Make sure you don't try to watch for a file in a resource directory. It feels like its working but its not because the file changes, but the resource doesn't reload automatically.

Comment: regarding to @mvmn  question, I was also wonder what is that variable for, so the only reasonable answer for me is, that code above was taken from something bigger and modified a little just for that example and that part `final WatchKey watchKey = ` wasn't delete. The most important is that the path was registered with watchservice `path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);`

Comment: in case anybody gets the modification event twice, here are some workarounds to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16777869

Answer (score 28):

Other answers are right that you must watch a directory and filter for your particular file. However, you probably want a thread running in the background. The accepted answer can block indefinitely on `watchService.take();` and doesn't close the WatchService. A solution suitable for a separate thread might look like:

```
public class FileWatcher extends Thread {
    private final File file;
    private AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public FileWatcher(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public boolean isStopped() { return stop.get(); }
    public void stopThread() { stop.set(true); }

    public void doOnChange() {
        // Do whatever action you want here
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            Path path = file.toPath().getParent();
            path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            while (!isStopped()) {
                WatchKey key;
                try { key = watcher.poll(25, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { return; }
                if (key == null) { Thread.yield(); continue; }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    Path filename = ev.context();

                    if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                        Thread.yield();
                        continue;
                    } else if (kind == java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY
                            && filename.toString().equals(file.getName())) {
                        doOnChange();
                    }
                    boolean valid = key.reset();
                    if (!valid) { break; }
                }
                Thread.yield();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Log or rethrow the error
        }
    }
}
```

I tried working from the accepted answer and [this article](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/file-change-notification-example-with-watch-service-api). You should be able to use this thread with `new FileWatcher(new File("/home/me/myfile")).start()` and stop it by calling `stopThread()` on the thread.

Comment: Remember that non-daemon threads prevent the JVM from exiting, so call `setDaemon(boolean)` prior to `run()` depending on how you want your app to behave.

Comment: in case anybody gets the modification event twice, here are some workarounds to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16777869

Comment: You might also want to reduce the priority of the thread.

Answer (score 21):

No it isn't possible to register a file, the watch service doesn't work this way. But **registering** a directory actually **watches** changes on the directory children (the files and sub-directories), not the changes on the directory itself.

If you want to watch a file, then you register the containing directory with the watch service. [Path.register() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#register%28java.nio.file.WatchService,%20java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind...%29) says:

> **WatchKey java.nio.file.Path.register(WatchService watcher, Kind[] events, Modifier...
>   modifiers) throws IOException**
>
> Registers the file located by this path with a watch service.
>
> In this release, this path locates a directory that exists. *The directory is **registered*** with the watch service *so that entries in the directory **can be watched***

Then you need to process events on entries, and detect those related to the file you are interested in, by checking the context value of the event. The context value represents the name of the entry (actually the path of the entry relatively to the path of its parent, which is exactly the child name). You have an [example here](http://markusjais.com/file-system-events-with-java-7/).

Answer (score 11):

Apache offers a [FileWatchDog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.html) class with a `doOnChange` method.

```
private class SomeWatchFile extends FileWatchdog {

    protected SomeWatchFile(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doOnChange() {
        fileChanged= true;
    }

}
```

And where ever you want you can start this thread:

```
SomeWatchFile someWatchFile = new SomeWatchFile (path);
someWatchFile.start();
```

The FileWatchDog class polls a file's `lastModified()` timestamp. The native WatchService from Java NIO is more efficient, since notifications are immediate.

Comment: Would be nice to know from which library the FileWatchdog class is coming from ?

Comment: from log4j - org.apache.log4j.helpers

Answer (score 9):

You cannot watch an individual file directly but you can filter out what you don't need.

Here is my `FileWatcher` class implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

public abstract class FileWatcher
{
    private Path folderPath;
    private String watchFile;

    public FileWatcher(String watchFile)
    {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(watchFile);

        boolean isRegularFile = Files.isRegularFile(filePath);

        if (!isRegularFile)
        {
            // Do not allow this to be a folder since we want to watch files
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(watchFile + " is not a regular file");
        }

        // This is always a folder
        folderPath = filePath.getParent();

        // Keep this relative to the watched folder
        this.watchFile = watchFile.replace(folderPath.toString() + File.separator, "");
    }

    public void watchFile() throws Exception
    {
        // We obtain the file system of the Path
        FileSystem fileSystem = folderPath.getFileSystem();

        // We create the new WatchService using the try-with-resources block
        try (WatchService service = fileSystem.newWatchService())
        {
            // We watch for modification events
            folderPath.register(service, ENTRY_MODIFY);

            // Start the infinite polling loop
            while (true)
            {
                // Wait for the next event
                WatchKey watchKey = service.take();

                for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchKey.pollEvents())
                {
                    // Get the type of the event
                    Kind<?> kind = watchEvent.kind();

                    if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY)
                    {
                        Path watchEventPath = (Path) watchEvent.context();

                        // Call this if the right file is involved
                        if (watchEventPath.toString().equals(watchFile))
                        {
                            onModified();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!watchKey.reset())
                {
                    // Exit if no longer valid
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void onModified();
}
```

To use this, you just have to extend and implement the `onModified()` method like so:

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyFileWatcher extends FileWatcher
{
    public MyFileWatcher(String watchFile)
    {
        super(watchFile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onModified()
    {
        System.out.println("Modified!");
    }
}
```

Finally, start watching the file:

```
String watchFile = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Test.txt";
FileWatcher fileWatcher = new MyFileWatcher(watchFile);
fileWatcher.watchFile();
```

Comment: clean working code! explanatory and well-written answer!

Comment: Actually it's missing the `OVERFLOW` case, so not a complete solution yet

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about others, but I groan at the amount of code needed to watch a single file for changes using the basic WatchService API. It has to be simpler!

Here are a couple of alternatives using third party libraries:

- [Using Apache Commons Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117117/dynamically-loading-properties-file-using-spring/14117183#14117183)
- [Using spring-loaded package from the Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/blob/master/springloaded/src/main/java/org/springsource/loaded/agent/FileSystemWatcher.java) (didn't find an example implementation for this off-hand, but it looks straight-forward to use)

Comment: The second link is still a lot of code around Java Watcher API

Answer (score 5):

I have created a wrapper around Java 1.7's `WatchService` that allows registering a directory and any number of *glob* patterns. This class will take care of the filtering and only emit events you are interested in.

```
try {
    DirectoryWatchService watchService = new SimpleDirectoryWatchService(); // May throw
    watchService.register( // May throw
            new DirectoryWatchService.OnFileChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFileCreate(String filePath) {
                    // File created
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileModify(String filePath) {
                    // File modified
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileDelete(String filePath) {
                    // File deleted
                }
            },
            <directory>, // Directory to watch
            <file-glob-pattern-1>, // E.g. "*.log"
            <file-glob-pattern-2>, // E.g. "input-?.txt"
            <file-glob-pattern-3>, // E.g. "config.ini"
            ... // As many patterns as you like
    );

    watchService.start(); // The actual watcher runs on a new thread
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Unable to register file change listener for " + fileName);
}
```

Complete code is in this [repo](https://github.com/Hindol/commons).

Answer (score 0):

I extended the solution by BullyWiiPlaza a bit, for integration with `javafx.concurrent`, e.g. `javafx.concurrent.Task`and `javafx.concurrent.Service`.
Also I added possibility to track multiple files.
Task:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

@Slf4j
public abstract class FileWatcherTask extends Task<Void> {

    static class Entry {
        private final Path folderPath;
        private final String watchFile;

        Entry(Path folderPath, String watchFile) {
            this.folderPath = folderPath;
            this.watchFile = watchFile;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Entry entry = (Entry) o;
            return Objects.equals(folderPath, entry.folderPath) && Objects.equals(watchFile, entry.watchFile);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(folderPath, watchFile);
        }
    }

    private final List<Entry> entryList;

    private final Map<WatchKey, Entry> watchKeyEntryMap;

    public FileWatcherTask(Iterable<String> watchFiles) {
        this.entryList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.watchKeyEntryMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (String watchFile : watchFiles) {
            Path filePath = Paths.get(watchFile);
            boolean isRegularFile = Files.isRegularFile(filePath);
            if (!isRegularFile) {
                // Do not allow this to be a folder since we want to watch files
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(watchFile + " is not a regular file");
            }
            // This is always a folder
            Path folderPath = filePath.getParent();
            // Keep this relative to the watched folder
            watchFile = watchFile.replace(folderPath.toString() + File.separator, "");
            Entry entry = new Entry(folderPath, watchFile);
            entryList.add(entry);
            log.debug("Watcher initialized for {} entries. ({})", entryList.size(), entryList.stream().map(e -> e.watchFile + "-" + e.folderPath).findFirst().orElse("<>"));
        }
    }

    public FileWatcherTask(String... watchFiles) {
        this(Arrays.asList(watchFiles));
    }

    public void watchFile() throws Exception {
        // We obtain the file system of the Path
        // FileSystem fileSystem = folderPath.getFileSystem();
        // TODO: use the actual file system instead of default
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();

        // We create the new WatchService using the try-with-resources block
        try (WatchService service = fileSystem.newWatchService()) {
            log.debug("Watching filesystem {}", fileSystem);
            for (Entry e : entryList) {
                // We watch for modification events
                WatchKey key = e.folderPath.register(service, ENTRY_MODIFY);
                watchKeyEntryMap.put(key, e);
            }

            // Start the infinite polling loop
            while (true) {
                // Wait for the next event
                WatchKey watchKey = service.take();
                for (Entry e : entryList) {
                    // Call this if the right file is involved
                    var hans = watchKeyEntryMap.get(watchKey);
                    if (hans != null) {
                        for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                            // Get the type of the event
                            WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = watchEvent.kind();

                            if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                                Path watchEventPath = (Path) watchEvent.context();
                                onModified(e.watchFile);
                            }
                            if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                                // Exit if no longer valid
                                log.debug("Watch key {} was reset", watchKey);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        watchFile();
        return null;
    }

    public abstract void onModified(String watchFile);
}
```

Service:

```
public abstract class FileWatcherService extends Service<Void> {
    
    private final Iterable<String> files;

    public FileWatcherService(Iterable<String> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new FileWatcherTask(files) {
            @Override
            public void onModified(String watchFile) {
                FileWatcherService.this.onModified(watchFile);
            }
        };
    }
    
    abstract void onModified(String watchFile);
}
```