# What does it mean for an event to be "repeated?"

Tags: java, events, watchservice

Reading the javadocs for `WatchEvent`, I see that the [`count()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchEvent.html#count%28%29) method lets me know if an event is repeated by its result.

> Returns the event count. If the event count is greater than 1 then this is a repeated event.

What does that mean, exactly? Does it mean that two or more `WatchEvent` objects refer to the same "event" (e.g. a file being created)?

I am experimenting with the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) on Oracle's site for the new `WatchService` API and this part confused me, especially because I will get a different number of events for successive runs of the same test code (in which I write to a file using a `FileWriter` without interacting with it manually), but the result of `count()` is never more than 1.

*Edit*: I realize that this may be related to [this other question about repeated events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777869/java-7-watchservice-ignoring-multiple-occurrences-of-the-same-event?rq=1), but that doesn't answer what it actually means for an event to be repeated.

Comment: Could it mean something like a double-click?

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't know, you tell me. I'm not even clicking on the file under question, so I can't tell.

Comment: I've never used this class--but if you're watching for files created in a directory, and then a file is created in the directory, and then later another file is created in the directory, maybe that's a repeated event?

Comment: @ajb I certainly hope it isn't, because then what's the point in checking if the `count` is greater than 1? I'd have to check the event context every time just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a while experimenting with this and this is my conclusion:

> **An event is repeated, for file `f` and event type `e`, if multiple `e` type events occurred to the same file `f`.**
>
> If an `e` type event occurred to multiple files `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, but only once each, then none of those events are repeated.

When you `.take()` a `WatchKey` from the `WatchService`, you will get a `WatchEvent` for each file which experienced an event, for each event type it experienced. The `.count()` will be greater than 1 if that type of event happened to that file multiple times since you last get a `WatchKey` from the `WatchService`.

That is, if you are watching a directory which has `A.txt` in it, and then the following events happen:

1. `B.txt` is created in the directory.
2. `B.txt` is written to.
3. `A.txt` is written to.
4. `B.txt` is deleted.
5. `A.txt` is written to again.

You will get four `WatchEvents`:

1. The create event for `B.txt`.
2. The modify event for `B.txt`.
3. The modify event for `A.txt`. Its `.count()` will be 2.
4. The delete event for `B.txt`.

This means that you will never get more than `3*n` events in your `WatchKey`, where `n` is the number of files that were in the directory at any point.

There are four types of events defined in [`StandardWatchEventKinds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html), but the `OVERFLOW` event indicates that events may have been lost, so I omitted it from the above number.

Comment: If all you're doing is say reading the file contents when you get a modify event, doesn't that mean you can just ignore duplicate/repeated events? As the contents of the file, at the time you handle the event is what matters and it doesn't seem like you could get the content on the first of repeated event?

Answer (score 0):

The watch service allows you to register a listener for events in directories.  If an event happens more than once before your service is notified, it gets an increment, instead of having two such events causing notification.

This is specifically about files, so it handles file creation, modification, deletion in a directory.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "an event happens more than once?" Say I modified two files in the directory before my `WatchService` noticed, will I get two modification events from `key.pollEvents()` or will I get one modification event with a count of 2?

Comment: The way I read the documentation, you monitor a directory; if two files were modified before the WatchService got around to constructing the notification, you would get one notification that two events had happened.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I was only modifying one file so I modified my test code to modify two files, and I got two modify events. I added a `wait` of 1 second before taking the events from the `WatchService` and I got two modify events, each with a count of 2 (probably for the same reason as in the linked question.) Does this mean that the `count` refers to the number of times a particular type of event happened to a particular file in that directory? e.g. if file `A.txt` was written to several times, the modify event with the `context()` `A.txt` would have a `count` greater than 1?