# Java how to detect file changes

Tags: java, file, events, actionlistener

Is there a way to somehow trigger an event that will do something every time a file change?
I mean something like that (in pseudo code)

```
if(DetectedFileModified(pathToFile)){ do stuff }
```

I know I can do it periodically but can I somehow do it without a timer? 
I want to be able to make some actions when a user is updating a txt file (not via code, but just by opening the file and writing inside) and I don't know when he'll do it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: What is your environment (e.g. Standalone, Application-Server, Eclipse-IDE, ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I watch for single file change with WatchService (not the whole directory)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251273/can-i-watch-for-single-file-change-with-watchservice-not-the-whole-directory)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

> The WatchService API is fairly low level, allowing you to customize it. You can use it as is, or you can choose to create a high-level API on top of this mechanism so that it is suited to your particular needs.

[Oracle blog on the same](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes)