# How to track, if a File has been renamed?

Tags: java, file-io, event-handling

I am continously reading a Logfile in realtime with a `BufferedReader`. This works pretty good. But every day there is a Log-rotate, which means my Logfile will be renamed and doesn't change anymore. A new Logfile will be created in the same place. Before I can change to that new Logfile, I need to finish reading the current one, which is no problem using `BufferedReader`, but how can I spot the filename has changed?

I tried calling `file.getPath()` and `file.getAbsolutePath()`, but this doesn't work, because the `File`-objects path is fixed after creation.

I also tried using the `WatchService`, but appending to the file causes a `ENTRY_DELETE` too. The resulting overead for checking if it was a rename is just to much.

Does anybody know a way to tell if the Logfile has been renamed?

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16251508/2071828) a while ago - hope it helps.

Comment: I found that answer and tried it, but, as I mentioned, the overhead to detect a rename instead of an append is to much.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how this is "too much overhead" at all.

Comment: It simply takes to long to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/). Does the job, though don't know of the resources it takes.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am looking for, unfortunately it is not avaiable for older os.