# Reinitialization of spring bean during runtime?

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem ."This is just a configuration which I would like to manage during runtime. I don't want to redeploy whole app to update configuration".I am reading some values from the property files.How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible solutions, depending on the exact need (and this like possibility to reload these properties on demand etc.).

The simplest one seems to be this one:

- Create a bean that internally has a cache defined (like Guava Cache)
- Set certain TTL for the cache contents (this will cause your properties to be reloaded every `TTL` seconds)
- Provide a way to populate the cache
- Optionally provide a way to force refresh of cache contents

As for the last point I cannot give you a way to do this because I know nothing of your project, but there are at least few good options here depending on the project you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is not part of deployable (WAR/EAR/JAR), you can watch for directory changes and identify whether your file has changed (refer [Can I watch for single file change with WatchService (not the whole directory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251273/can-i-watch-for-single-file-change-with-watchservice-not-the-whole-directory)). Once you notice the file has changed, you can execute your logic.