# When running 2 instances of a .jar I want to read/write to same file?

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, instance

I want to be able to launch multiple instances of a .jar, than when one updates a file "test".ser. to have the other instance present that change, pretty much the same way it would do i within the same instance.

Basically created two instance and see if data changes on different pages, does change within same instance but does not update on second instance?

All files are in same spot. I am using .ser files.

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fin3 = new FileInputStream("buildingEntryList.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois3 = new ObjectInputStream(fin3);
        List<TreeMap> list = (ArrayList) ois3.readObject();

        for (TreeMap s : list){
            Building.buildingEntryList.add(s);
        }

        ois3.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Comment: Or is it just worth my time to learn mysql

Comment: Tis Worth it. Learn.

Comment: Well, SQL and JDBC generally. I usually suggest either H2 or Postgres.

Comment: This sounds like maybe there is a better way but if you just want to watch for a file creation or modification there is a way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251273/can-i-watch-for-single-file-change-with-watchservice-not-the-whole-directory