# Sharing docker envinroment

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, repository

What's the right way to share environment and code between team members?
I need this for local development. In my vision, a developer download from a git repo the environment (basically a docker compose with subfolders and configuration), then pull from another repo the code and put it inside the right folder of the previous structure.

```
REPO1 -> docker-compose with configuration, specific Dockerfile etc.
REPO2 -> code
```

So I'll have two separate, and then nested, git repositories, at this point I can build and deploy the whole thing. Is it the right path?

- Should I build a docker image and share that, instead of the
  environment details? Can I then pull code and insert it?
- How do you commit empty folder (the one that    will be used to host
  the code) in a git repository without using the    ".keep file"
  trick?

As you can see I'm a newbie and have quite a bit of confusion in my head.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you hoping to get from using Docker here?  Why is the repository of code insufficient?  It's common to keep Docker-related artifacts in the application repository itself (a `Dockerfile` that builds a self-contained image of the application that doesn't require bind mounts; a `docker-compose.yml` that can run the application and its dependencies) which potentially simplifies things.

Comment: Yeah but that way i'll have different repositories between local/dev/prod. Even if similar they surely have something different, so I can't mix code and infrastructure.

Comment: Do you want to share containers and its configurations to all members of your team?

Comment: @JRichardsz exactly.

Comment: Will this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60780840/3957754 ?